# how to check if user has already signed up or not in firebase via google account in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to do an action for user that **login for the first time** (signed up) using google account and another action if the user has already login before.

if some user has been and still logged in using their Google account, we can use this lines of code

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
    if user == nil {
        self.goToLoginVC()
    }
}
```

but how can I differentiate if a user login for the first time (signed up) or not ? is there any particular method to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UserDefault` to check the same. Just maintain the flag to check

like

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()


   Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil {
             if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "uid") != nil && Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
              //User was already logged in 
               }

             UserDefaults.standard.setValue(user?.uid, forKeyPath: "uid")

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "CurrentlyLoggedIn", sender: nil)

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused because you wrote "//User was already logged in" within your if statement and also have the identifier "CurrentlyLoggedIn" outside and below your if statement. To me these seem synonymous. Also, there's no code, or explanation of code, inside your `UserDefaults.standard.string.....` statement so I'm not exactly sure what happens within here. Do the lines below the if statement still get executed regardless?

Comment: @Jacob  `if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "uid") != nil && Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {` This makes you confuse ?, Yes you are right this line inside the block doesn't make sense.  This is line is just for  show that  how you can check that user is logged in or not at other places or in other classes

Comment: I'm confused because it doesn't look like there's a case for when the user is new. Also with that if statement, every login I make is has the same outcome regardless of whether or not I'd signed in using that gmail

Comment: @Jacob  **doesn't look like there's a case for when the user is new** --> No There is many cases where user may not be logged in  And As I told you If statement is just for demo purpose it will be out of the that block

Comment: I meant it looks like if the user is a previous user, then all the code inside the if statement  `if user != nil` is executed, and if the user if new then only the last two lines are inside the if statment `if user != nil` are executed. I'm trying to test it out in my program, but the if statement `if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "uid") != nil && Auth.auth().currentUser != nil ` always returns false for me, with any account. The first condition inside the nested if statement always returns false, while the second one always returns true.

Comment: It might also be important that I removed the line `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()` because I do my login just with a button click.

Comment: I posted my own question because none of the answers I could find worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360353/gidsignin-with-swift-and-firebase-checking-if-the-user-is-a-new-or-returning-us